# Python: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'right'

Tags: python, tree, traversal, attributeerror, nonetype

I can't seem to understand why I am getting this error. There are cases where check.right is None and if the two conditions (check.right != None) & (check.right == stack[-1]) are not met it will just enter the else condition.

Here's the code: (it's a postordertraversal iteration with node class: self.val, self.left, self.right)

```
class TreeNode:
def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

class Solution:
def postorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
    stack=[]
    output=[]
    node = root
    while True:
        if node:
            stack.append(node.right)
            stack.append(node)
            node=node.left
        elif stack:
            check=stack.pop()
            if stack:
                if (check.right != None) & (check.right == stack[-1]):
                    node=stack.pop()
                    stack.append(check)
            else:
                output.append(check.val)
                node=None
        else:
            break
    return output
```

Comment: if possible, you should add the code for your other Classes as well... TreeNode and List unless the Classes keep referencing other classes.

Comment: Post the traceback message which includes the failing line.

Comment: Can you add error details?

Comment: If `node.right` is `None` and is appended to `stack`, `check=stack.pop()` is `None` and `check.right` raises the error.

Comment: Hi tdelaney, you're right about appending when node.right is None, but what do you mean by : 'check.right raises the error'?

Comment: Just to confirm you were referring to the conditional check of check.right == stack[-1] when check.right is None ?